# Transpose 2 associative arrays of unequal size to form an associative 2d array

Tags: php, merge, associative-array, transpose

Example:

```
$arr1 = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'z' => "4");
$arr2 = array('a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7", 'd' => "6", 'e' => "5");
```

Output:

```
$result = array(
    'a' => array( 'f1' => "1", 'f2' => "9"),
    'b' => array( 'f1' => "2", 'f2' => "8"),
    'c' => array( 'f1' => "3", 'f2' => "7"),
    'd' => array( 'f1' => "0", 'f2' => "6"),
    'e' => array( 'f1' => "0", 'f2' => "5"),
    'z' => array( 'f1' => "4", 'f2' => "0"),
);
```

The size of $arr1 can be '>', '<' or '=' size of $arr2

Comment: Are non-existing values filled with `"0"`?

Comment: Sure looks that way. He'll need a double pass.

Comment: What have you got so far D3VELOPER?

Comment: D3VELOPER, what webbiedave was getting at, it is obvious you have not tried this on your own and giving us an example of what you have tried will help us "correct" you where you went wrong. But not showing us code is like you are demanding this of us. Because of this I have removed my solution as it could be job / homework related and me just providing you with the answer teaches you nothing. If you do have supporting code to show, please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this it,

```
$arr1 = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'z' => "4");

$arr2 = array('a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7", 'd' => "6", 'e' => "5");


foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $a[$key]['f1'] = $value;
}

foreach($arr2 as $key => $value){
    $b[$key]['f2'] = $value;
}

$c = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);
foreach($c as $key => $value){
    $result[$key]['f1'] = (array_key_exists('f1', $value)) ? $value['f1']: 0;
    $result[$key]['f2'] = (array_key_exists('f2', $value)) ? $value['f2']: 0;
}

echo "<pre>".print_r ($result, true);
```

the output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 1
            [f2] => 9
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 2
            [f2] => 8
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 3
            [f2] => 7
        )

    [z] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 4
            [f2] => 0
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 0
            [f2] => 6
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [f1] => 0
            [f2] => 5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

array_merge_recursive() should work: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

otherwise it's simple enough wo implement in a few lines: (Unless you *really* need the "fn" indices.)

```
function my_merge(){

    $result = array();
    foreach(func_get_args() as $a)
        foreach($a as $index => $value)
            $result[$index][] = $value;         

}
```

Comment: Relax your requirements for the data format, and you can simplify the code by several orders of magnitude. Unless it *really, really* must have exactly the format in your example, it's a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: Neither `array_merge_recursive()`, nor this generalized transposition snippet will produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2)));
$values = array_map(function($key) use ($arr1, $arr2) {
    return array('f1' => isset($arr1[$key]) ? $arr1[$key] : "0",
                 'f2' => isset($arr2[$key]) ? $arr2[$key] : "0"); }
    , $keys);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
var_dump($result);
```

Some explanation:

- At first get an array `$keys` of all unique keys of both arrays.
- Then for each key the corresponding array of values is then generated.
- At last the array of keys and the array of values are combined.

But this does currently only work with two arrays.

---

**Edit**    Here’s one that works with an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
$arrays = array($arr1, $arr2);
$keys = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map('array_keys', $arrays)));
$values = array_map(function($key) use ($arrays) {
    return array_combine(array_map(function($key) {
        return 'f'.($key+1);
    }, array_keys($arrays)),
    array_map(function($array) use ($key) {
        return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : "0";
    }, $arrays));
}, $keys);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
var_dump($result);
```

Some explanation:

- Put all arrays in an array `$arrays`.
- For each array in `$arrays`, call `array_keys` on it to get the keys, merge these arrays and get an array `$keys` of all unique keys.
- For each key in `$keys`, check if the key exists in the array of arrays `$arrays`.
- Combine the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'z' => "4");

$arr2 = array('a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7", 'd' => "6", 'e' => "5");

function combineArray($arr1, $arr2) {
    if (is_array($arr1) && is_array($arr2)) {
        $rArr = array();
        $steps = max ( count($arr1),count($arr2));
     $ak1 = array_keys($arr1);
     $ak2 = array_keys($arr2);

        for ($i=0;$i<$steps;$i++) {
                if (!isset($rArr[$i])) $rArr[$i]=array();
                $rArr[$i]['f1'] = (isset($arr1[$ak1[$i]])) ? $arr1[$ak1[$i]]: '0';
                $rArr[$i]['f2'] = (isset($arr2[$ak2[$i]])) ? $arr2[$ak2[$i]]: '0';
        }
        return $rArr;

    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

echo "<pre>".print_r (combineArray($arr1, $arr2),true);
```

might work :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run through the first array, store the `f1` values from the array and set the default `0` for all `f2` values.
2. Run through the second array, store the `f2` values from the array and only set the default `0` for the respective `f1` value if it is not already declared.
3. Use `ksort()` if desired to alphabetize the first level keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YensZ))

```
$array1 = ['a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'z' => "4"];
$array2 = ['a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7", 'd' => "6", 'e' => "5"];

$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ['f1' => $v, 'f2' => "0"];
}
foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ['f1' => $result[$k]['f1'] ?? "0", 'f2' => $v];
}

var_export($result);
```